# debugging root application on linux with GDB

Tags: debugging, process, gdb

I'm studying on a book called "the art of hacking" and after the theory, I'm trying to do some exercises on real old vulnerabilities just to do some exercises.

So, I "configure", "make" and "make install" an ftp vulnerable service and then I launch it as root.

At this point, I need to debug the ftp service while it is running as root. 
What I have understood from the book is that, to create a working exploit for a case like that, I need to study the stack while the service is running as root in order to have a real "stack situation" of the program on which I want to work... and to do it I need to attach my gdb to the running process!

My problem is that when I launch the command

gdb

my gdb is attaching to the process, BUT of course I have any symbol loaded and any possibility to study the stack of the program.

Since I have all the sources of the application, how can I compile them in order to create the symbols needed to debug the running process?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `-g` to the compile flags.  Most packages will do this with `configure --enable-debug`, but you may need to do something like set the `CFLAGS` environment variable using `export CFLAGS=-g` before running configure if that doesn't work.